# Comment a line of code in a SqlDataSource in ASP.NET markup

Tags: asp.net, comments

I normally use

```
<%-- Comment/or line of code --%>
```

to comment out a line of code in asp.net mark up.
Sometimes I just select the line that I like to comment out and press

> ctrl+(k, c)

to automatically comment out the line or

> ctrl+(k, u)

to uncomment the line. For some reason, I cannot comment out a line of code in a SqlDataSource this way. Something like this gives an error:

```
.......
<%--SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [myTable] ORDER BY [Code]"--%>
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [anotherTable] ORDER BY [Code]"
.........
```

I wonder why I am getting an error in such cases? Is there a way to comment out a line of code in a SqlDataSource in the markup?

Comment: Comments are not allowed between the `<` and `>` characters of the start tag of a `runat="server"` control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michael said, such comments are not allowed. However you can use SQL comments within the property value, for example:

```
SelectCommand="/*SELECT * FROM [myTable] ORDER BY [Code]*/SELECT * FROM [anotherTable] ORDER BY [Code]"
```